# Send/Receive http request/response from MS Word addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a add-in for MS Word. Is it possible to for a MS Word add-in to listen on specific port and send/receive http request/response? Will there be a firewall between MS Word and an application that is running outside of Word?

Answer (score 1):

An Office AddIn can make HTTP requests without triggering a firewall issue (using Windows Firewall in its default configuration), but it can't listen without triggering firewall issues.

If you're making requests from inside word to a service you have living outside of Word that service may encounter Firewall issues while listening on a port.

Windows Firewall, by default [blocks incoming requests](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/understanding-windows-firewall-settings). Windows Firewall is included with all versions of Windows XP SP2 or later.

See [MSDN for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140260%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

Additionally,

```
Function GetRateCBR(dDate As Date) As String
Dim sUrlRequest, intTry As Integer, _
    strResponse As String
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
Dim oResponse As Object

Set oResponse = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

'Build URL for request
sUrlRequest = _
    "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=" _
    & Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") _
    & "&date_req2=" & Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") _
    & "&VAL_NM_RQ=" & "R01235"

'Try to get a response, 10 tries
intTry = 1
Do Until intTry > 10
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sUrlRequest, False
    oXMLHTTP.send
    If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        If oResponse.loadXML(oXMLHTTP.responseText) Then _
            Exit Do
    End If
    If Not oXMLHTTP Is Nothing Then oXMLHTTP.abort: _
        Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
    DoEvents
    intTry = intTry + 1
Loop
If Not oXMLHTTP Is Nothing Then oXMLHTTP.abort: _
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
If intTry <= 10 Then
     GetRateCBR = Mid$(oResponse.Text, 3)
End If
If Not oResponse Is Nothing Then oResponse.abort: _
    Set oResponse = Nothing
End Function
```

Example via [Access Blog](http://accessblog.net/2006/12/how-to-retrieve-data-from-web-server.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you have an example of how to setup in C#? Or is it just common to write a MS Word Add-in using VB?